# Password Protecting directory using Apache and windows authentication? NOT .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication

For part of my assignment, I had to create two local directories in my Apache htdocs path and password protect them so that only one user can access them.  I did this using htaccess. However, this was apparently the wrong answer because they wanted authentication using windows user login user/pwd.

I don't understand how i can do this.  How can i create a folder that is only accessible by the user with the same name?

Thanks for any advice.  I do not need a solution, just some information on where to start looking.  Everything I find seems to require htaccess.  Unless i am thinking of this wrong and there is a module i can use with htaccess to make this work.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Windows_Authentication

Comment: thanks i looked into it and it is probably what she wanted.  thanks

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what your prof is looking for but you can probably do this by working with the windows folder sharing and permission options

[Setting folder Share permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3zAh.png)

Comment: unfortunately, that is not what i needed.